# Is there any C++ "Code Generator" out there?

Tags: c++

I've been reading about Meta II, and that made me wonder if there was a C++ "Code Generator". I looked for a C++ Metacompiler, but that is not exactly what I'm referring to. What I'm referring to is something similar to how macros work in Assembly.

To clarify, I'm not talking about templating or defining. I'm also not talking about using an IDE to generate code for me. This is NOT a theoretical issue, it would be extremely useful to me. I'm working on projects where I need access to the code, and I need it to be "mine". Using the functions from the STL makes things worst many times. It will also save a lot of time on trivial tasks when the algorithm is firstly being implemented.

I'm talking about a tool containing a database of templated code snippets that could be inserted by either using macros or a visual GUI. That way further manipulation of the code could be done after the basic framework is set up.

Example: I have a queue of objects. I want to find a certain type of object within that queue. There would be a code snippet that could be inserted that will automatically generate a function (member, static, friend...) that would traverse my queue and seek for certain conditions. Different than the IDE, I won't be giving details such as parameters or returning type. Only the very basic will be generated. Maybe in this case a reference to the member. It will give me a prototype and a basic function definition. Further customization will need to be done manually.

When implementing an algorithm in C++, you have to translate it to some of the technicalities even before you can get anything done. Whereas in Software Engineering those technicalities take a big role, in a simple algorithm development they don't (KIS).

### More details:

Adding example. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear. I didn't know what terms to use for some of the features I tried to describe (English is not my first language). I should have included an example.

Here is the main idea: I have an algorithm and the pseudocode for it. The tool I'm looking for would reduce the time for first implementing that pseudocode. With few lines or a GUI, a lot of the trivial part of coding C++ would be done automatically (Like indenting, creating for-loops for traversing, declaring iterators and temporary variables, etc...). Design considerations would be done in a standard way (E.g: return a pointer or reference, use iterator or index, etc...). Libraries would be automatically included. Classes, function prototypes and functions definitions generated will be distributed in a standard way in your code. I'm not specifically limiting to my description, but this is the kind of thing I'm looking for in such tool.

Here is a quick example:

### Formula for generation:

I came up with some sort of language/macro as an example. But anything similar would do.
Legend: # - indicate it is a variable

```
class Time(int #day, string #name) //Create `class` Time with `int` day and string name
  getter getName #name //Create a member function to get name

main//Main
  vector Time #vec //Create vector of Time vec 
  input int #var1 //Input `int`
  find #var1 #day #vec //Find a member with day equal to var1 in vec
  printVector #vec  //Call print function for vector

function printVector(vector #par1) //Create void function printVector() to output names of Time instances
   output #par1 //Print member variables from vector
```

### Code generated:

The decisions for automatic variables, temporary variables, iterators, or any other design consideration would be already predefined. The above required at least some thinking for coming up with the "language", whereas I've written the code below so many times that I did not even "think". Still, it took much, much longer to write the code below (And it's more prone to contain simple errors that are hard to spot).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//Create `class` Time with `int` day and string name
class Time
{
  int day;
  string name;

public:
  Time() {};
  Time(int par1, string par2) {day = par1; name = par2;}
  string getName() const {return name;} //Create a member function to get name
};

template<typename T> void printVector(vector<T>);

//Main
int main()
{
  vector<Time> vec; //Create vector of Time vec 
  int var1; cin>>var1; cin.ignore(); //Input `int` var1 (Default using iostream)

  //Find a member with day equal to var1 in vec (First found by default)
  vector<Time>::iterator it1; bool found = false;
  for(it1 = vec.begin(); (it1 != vec.end() && !found); found = (it1->day == var1), it1++);

  printVector(vec); //Call printVector

  return 0;
}

//Create void function printVector() to output name from vector
template<typename T>
void printVector(vector<T> par1)
{

  //Print member variables of instances from vector 
  vector<Time>::iterator it1;
  for(it1 = par1.begin(); it1 != par1.end(); it1++)
    cout<<it1->day<<" "<<it1->name; //Would cause an error since can't access, but generator doesn't know it!
}
```

Hopefully I better clarified what is the type of tool that I'm looking for. I really can't see why some got so frustrated about what I want. I completely disagree that it would be useless. And as long as the syntax used is kept at a basic level, I don't see why there would be that many compatibility problems.
I was thinking about doing it myself with a GUI. But since it is such a simple concept (Nothing even closer to what a Meta-compiler does), I was confident there would be already something like that out there.

Comment: What exactly is is about your task that makes templates unsuitable? Could you clarify your queue example by being more explicit about what you want to see at each step.

Comment: The best code generation tool is a programmer :)

Comment: Why not just write in a higher level language?  Most scripting languages support extensions in C++ so if need be you can drop down to C++ to optimise hot-spots.

Comment: Roll whatever you need with ruby or similar.  Most code generation tasks are very domain specific, so I doubt you'll find a database of snippets anywhere.

Comment: it sounds like you want a duck typing language or something? there's a great database of snippets for C++ called STL and the auto keyword comes in handy but that doesn't seem like enough for you

Comment: I wish I could vote for closing this question on the grounds of incomprehensibility and delusions

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you basically want a set of wizards to insert algorithmic code for you, that you can just hack around.  Cut and paste programming on steroids, with all the distributed bugs and code bloat that implies.  Sorry to say I haven't heard of such a tool....

Comment: It's called Internet: you search, copy code you don't understand, ask questions, copy the solutions you don't understand, ...

Comment: "Example: I have a queue of objects. I want to find a certain type of object within that queue" - step 1, modify your queue so that it can return `begin()` and `end()` iterators. Step 2, use `std::find_if`, passing it a predicate that tests whether an object or isn't of the required type. You only need to do Step 1 once for the queue, regardless of how many different operations you use those iterators for. If you get this right, it's better than copy-pasting into each operation a code snippet for a queue-specific loop that looks through the queue.

Comment: @SteveJessop, you should write that as an actual answer :)

Comment: Clarifications:
1) Copying from the internet would take too long. I have my own code snippets. Yet, not nearly as fast and mutable as what I said. 2) I'm sorry if it is incomprehensible, but I'm not delusional... 3) I would actually use it whenever I code in C++ (Even if I'm coding an extension) 4) I'm honestly surprised on how "crazy" my idea sounds. I thought there would be many tools like that. Well, maybe I am indeed delusional after all :).

Comment: It's not crazy. I think, but I'm not sure (still haven't gotten around to acquiring it...), that you are looking for some of the techniques described in the book "Code Generation In Action".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're unlikely to find something exactly like you ask for - code duplication (which is what your proposed method of expand-in-place templates would create) is generally considered a bad thing, both because it decreases code comprehensibility and because it raises the possibility of copying buggy code around. Using C++ built-in (non-expanded) templates (and the STL) is generally recommended - if you're having such problems with it, you should be more clear about what your problems are so we might be able to help there too.

However, if you absolutely must have shortcut templates, Eclipse supports something like this. Take a look at [this tutorial on Eclipse code templates.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/index.html) Note that these templates are pure string substitutions, and are somewhat limited. I would *strongly* recommend against including any kind of complex logic in such a template.

Comment: I see what you are saying (Good answer, btw). I should probably have specified better with a specific example to make myself clear. I didn't know about the term code-duplication. I'm not sure what is meant by expand-in-place, but I'm guessing it refers to having a piece of code that have to be expanded in the middle of my code. But I was proposing was more something that I could organize a basic background for my algorithm that would generate code entirely in C++  the most basic way. I'll edit my question and hopefully it will be more clear. However, I'm already guessing there is no such tool.